# NodeJS - Can I detect when called from command line (ES6 + Babel)..?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

In my module I need to detect when it's being called from either the command line, or from another module.

```
const isFromCLI = '????'
```

I'm using Babel/ES6, so when called from a command line, `index.js` is called (with the babel code), which hands off to `script.js` (with ES6 code). So from the script file, `module.parent` returns `module` (the `index.js` file). **So I can't use** `module.parent`!

Also, `module.main` is `undefined` (in `script.js`) when called from either the command line or from another module. **So I can't use** `module.main`!

Those are the two solutions that others are suggesting, but they don't work for me.

Is there a simple to detect this when using Babel/ES6..?

**Update**

`require.main` returns `module` when called from either the command line or from another module.

Comment: Please show us how you are invoking the code. If, as you say, `index.js` is called from the command line which hands off to `script.js`, then `script.js` is *not* called directly from the command line? Seems fine to me.

Comment: @Bergi You're correct, `script.js` is not called directly from the command line. However `index.js` only contains the Babel code required for `script.js` to work. I see what you're saying though. I thought there might be a different way to detect this, rather than seeing if `module.parent` is equal to `module`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Process`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv) in Node.

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv

Check the value of the second parameter (do a contains type match). Not sure if this is the only way but it's a straight forward way to achieve what you need

A code snippet might be:

```
 const isFromCLI = (process.argv[1].indexOf('my-script.js') !== -1);
```

Comment: This does work, the second element is the path to the js file being executed, which in my case is different. It's a bit of a work around, but does work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Node Environment Variables](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env).

You can set an environment variable like this:

`CLI=true node app.js`

and then get the environment variable like this:

`const isFromCLI = process.env.CLI === 'true'`

**Note:** `process.env.CLI` will be a string.

**Update:**

If you want to do something like `node app.js --cli`, you can do the following:

```
let isFromCLI

process.argv.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
  if (array[index] === '--cli') {
    isFromCLI = true
  }
})

console.log(isFromCLI)
```

Comment: This would work, however, ideally I want to avoid changing what I use on the command line. I could just as easy add an cli option `node app.js --cli`.

Comment: @StephenLast, Updated.